# How to install modules with Python 2.4.3

Tags: python, module, python-2.4

I could not find anything on google about installing modules on this particular version 2.4.3 so I'm asking here.

I need to install python-ssl to use ssl package with python 2.4.3

I do not have any Scripts/pip.exe in my Python24 folder...

I've tried most commands yum / pip etc... nothing seems to work.

How to proceed please ?

Comment: Why are you using a version of Python that has been out of date for more than a decade?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm on windows to create scripts. It is for a Linux server which uses tons of scripts on python 2.4

Answer (score 2):

You would probably need to make use of one of [ancient methods of installation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/install/). Try download [ssl file from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/ssl/#files), unpack it, go to catalog which was created when you unpacked it and do `python setup.py install`.